# aptitude 404 Not Found [IP: 64.50.233.100 80] error

Tags: aptitude

ím trying to install, remove, update some packages in my debian box:

todasana:~# cat /proc/version
Linux version 2.6.18-6-686 (Debian 2.6.18.dfsg.1-18etch1) (waldi@debian.org) (gcc version 4.1.2 20061115 (prerelease) (Debian 4.1.1-21)) #1 SMP Sun Feb 10 22:11:31 UTC 2008

And getting some package to download fine, and a not found error to some of the packages:

> ftp.us.debian.org etch/main Packages
>   [ERROR]
>   404 Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]
>   ftp.us.debian.org etch/non-free
>   Packages [ERROR]
>   404 Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]
>   security.debian.org
>   etch/updates/non-free Sources [Hit]
>   ftp.us.debian.org etch/contrib
>   Packages [ERROR]
>   404 Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]
>   ftp.us.debian.org etch/main Sources
>   [ERROR]
>   404 Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]
>   ftp.us.debian.org etch/non-free
>   Sources [ERROR]
>   404 Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]
>   ftp.us.debian.org etch/contrib Sources
>   [ERROR]
>   404 Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]

This on particular appears when i hit u for update on python module, then it says, some files were not downloaded successfully. I fear to have a bunch of broken gear on my server, that won´t work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your /etc/apt/sources.list has etch hardcoded rather than stable.

I'm not sure if etch is still on the repositories since they are using lenny/squeeze/sid right now.

If you still need etch, you might be able to find an archive or backports mirror, but, etch hasn't received any security patches since Feb 2010 or so.

Comment: i don´t really need etch, added this line: deb http://archive.debian.org/debian/ etch main non-free contrib to the /etc/apt/sources.list and commented the other ones, and it worked, how ever, i guess i should upgrade since i dont have a lot of things mounted there, and we are going to need things organized for projects to come. Can you point me to the right direction to do this? tutorials and files ? its been a long time since i don´t linux my life

Comment: ried but everything got messed up in the upgrade, so i backed things up and restarted a fresh new installation from a lenny cd. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

update package index files

```
aptitude update
```

Comment: hello, aptitude update gives me the same errors on some files

Comment: update to lenny:
cp /etc/apt/sources.list ~/sources.list;
sed -i 's/lucid/lenny/' /etc/apt/sources.list;
sudo apt-get update;
sudo aptitude install apt dpkg aptitude;
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade;

or if stable in sources.list, use apt-get dist-upgrade

Comment: tried but everything got messed up in the upgrade, so i backed things up and restarted a fresh new installation from a lenny cd. Thank you